# c# MVC code for the Editing Button, but clicking on the Edit button does not post it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern

I use the following code for the Editing Button, but clicking on the Edit button does not post it

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "PageID,GroupID,Title,ShortDescription,Text,Autor,Tags,Visit,ImageName,ShowInSlider,CreatDateTime")] Page page,HttpPostedFileBase imgUp)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (imgUp != null)
            {
                if (page.ImageName != null)
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("/PageImages/" + page.ImageName));
                }



                page.ImageName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(imgUp.FileName);
                imgUp.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/PageImages/" + page.ImageName));
            }


            pageRepository.UpdatePage(page);
            pageRepository.save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

....

I have separate data layer and repository and I use the following code for the Editing Pages Controller, but with clicking on the Edit button does not post form. Though it works well for creation and delete btn. my view code is:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Page</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PageID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Visit)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreatDateTime)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ImageName)


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GroupID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("GroupID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GroupID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    ....

           <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImageName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" name="imgUp"  id="imgUp"/>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImageName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @if (Model.ImageName != null)
            {
                <img src="/PageImages/@Model.ImageName" class="thumbnail" style="max-width:150px"  />

            }

    .....



    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

i trace my code and find this eror:

```
 Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Request","time":"2018-04-25T08:10:44.3663705Z","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"web: 2.0.0.25000","ai.device.roleInstance":"Laptop-erfan","ai.operation.name":"GET PageGroup
```

above horizontal form tag is this code:

```
@model DataLayer.Page
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit";}<h2>Edit</h2>@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Pages", FormMethod.Post, new {  enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){ @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Comment: You need to show us the code in your view so we can see how the edit button is coded.

Comment: my view code for this part:

Comment: for normal post request, you need to wrap what you gonna post, in a form

Comment: I can't see any `form` in your code

Comment: Is there any code above <div class="form-horizontal"> ? there should be  model declaration and razor form tag. your entire form should be inside that tag.as @Jacky said.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments it doesn't look like you have a form in your view. You can add one using:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
       <!-- form contentshere -->
   }
```

BeingForm has several overloads as well that you can use to change where it goes to, form method (GET/PUT) and set html attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the complete form page into a Form tag.
please Use

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  //Put your complete code inside this form...
}
```

It will create the Form tag with specified actions and type.
You can also specific the custom action method and type of the method as well.